# mysqli_query expects parameter 1 to be mysqli AND problems with mysqli_fetch_all

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem and I've looked around online but I can't find the answer becuse the problems that are brought up aren't exactly the same as mine. I have a project in school where we are supposed to create a blog using php, mysqli, html, css and JavaScript. For the database part I found a site where they showed an example of how you can write the code. My problem: the code isn't working. I have one php-document where I have included different other documents, one of which contain a function with the following code:

```
global $connect;
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", NULL, "database");
```

After I included the document with this code I included another with the following code:

```
<?php

/* Returns all published posts
 */
function getPublishedPosts() {

    // use global $connect in function
    global $connect;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE published=true";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

    // fetch all posts as an associative array called $posts
    $posts = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    return $posts;
}

// more functions to come here ...
?>
```

This is the code that I'm having trouble with, I'm getting the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: connect in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\pfunctions.php
>   on line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\pfunctions.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\pfunctions.php on line 13

I have tried making $connect global in both docs, making it global only in the last one (the way it was in the tutorial) I have tried adding the entire code of $connect to the second doc and it's just not working.

Second **I read that mysqli_fetch_all() only works if you have mysqli driver** and I don't think my school does and I have no idea how to write it instead, and I hoped you guys could help me with that as well. I'm very new to this so please don't be too hard on me. Thank you!

Comment: How exactly are you calling `$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", NULL, "database");`? I don't see any require or include in your script

Comment: @hungrykoala I call it with db_connect () later in the second document.

Comment: @hungrykoala (db_connect is the function that $connect is a part of)

Comment: You're not calling that in the current script. That's why it returns null as it cannot find it.